# How to disable all even dates or odd dates upon choosing even or odd date in datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to achieve the following: if the selected month has odd number of days, the even days are disabled, on the opposite, the odd days are disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can do the above thing using the below technique. If you require the opposite scenario then just flip the disabled flag and then its done. The below code can be used directly in your application.

```js
    $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
              var disabled = true, // enabled default day
                // total days of current month
                numOfDays = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
                    if (numOfDays % 2 == 0) {
                        disabled = (date.getDate() % 2 == 0) //so for even days months, disable the odd days
                    } else {
                        disabled = (date.getDate() % 2 != 0) //so for odd days months, disable the even days
                    }
                    return [disabled, ""]
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```